# How to pass form id if there are several forms on page and no submit buttons Django 1.10?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a page with list of questions. Each of them has radio button form with "Yes", "Maybe", "No" kind of choices. This form's submits by making a choice.
http://prntscr.com/embo1m

I can't understand how to connect question id with it's form. How to get it in it's view with response?

models.py

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice = models.IntegerField(default=2)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.choice)
```

views.py

```
def questions_list(request, apartment_pk):
    context = {}
    context['apartment'] = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_pk)
    context['questions'] = get_list_or_404(Question)
    context['answer_form'] = AnswerForm
    context['username'] = auth.get_user(request).username
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
    return render(request, 'main/questions.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    choice = ChoiceField(label='', widget=RadioSelect, choices=ANSWERS)
    question_id = CharField(widget=HiddenInput(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('choice', 'question_id')
```

template

```
<h1>{{ apartment.title }}</h1>
{% for question in questions %}
<h3>{{ question.title }}</h3>
<form id="question_{{ question.id }}" name="question_{{ question.id }}" action="/apartments/{{ apartment.id }}/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for radio in answer_form.choice %}
        <label><input name="choice" type="radio" value="{{ radio.choice_value }}" onchange="question_{{ question.id }}.submit()">{{ radio.choice_label }}</label>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ answer_form.hidden_field }}
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

#### EDIT:

Tried to pass question id as `<input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="{{ question.id }}">`

```
<h1>{{ apartment.title }}</h1>
{% for question in questions %}
<h3>{{ question.title }}</h3>
    <form id="question_{{ question.id }}" name="question_{{ question.id }}" action="/apartments/{{ apartment.id }}/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="{{ question.id }}">
        {% for radio in answer_form.choice %}
            <label><input name="choice" type="radio" value="{{ radio.choice_value }}" onchange="question_{{ question.id }}.submit()">{{ radio.choice_label }}</label>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

And changed my form to

```
class AnswerForm(Form):
    choice = ChoiceField(label='', widget=RadioSelect, choices=ANSWERS)
```

But there's no hidden input in form from response...

```
<tr><th></th><td><ul id="id_choice">
    <li><label for="id_choice_0"><input id="id_choice_0" name="choice" type="radio" value="0" required /> Точно ні</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_choice_1"><input id="id_choice_1" name="choice" type="radio" value="1" required /> Скоріше ні</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_choice_2"><input checked="checked" id="id_choice_2" name="choice" type="radio" value="2" required /> Не можу відповісти</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_choice_3"><input id="id_choice_3" name="choice" type="radio" value="3" required /> Скоріше так</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_choice_4"><input id="id_choice_4" name="choice" type="radio" value="4" required /> Точно так</label></li>
</ul></td></tr>
```

Cleaned data `{'choice': '2'}`

Comment: Do you want to the page to reload after form submission?

Comment: FYI HTML `id`s **must not have only numbers**. Change it to something like this `form id="form-{{ question.id }}"`

Comment: @AbijithMg No, if it's possible without JS. In the other way reload is acceptable.

Comment: Its very difficult without using JS to submit the appropriate form.

Comment: @nik_m changed it to `form id="question_{{ question.id }}"`

Comment: Still, how to pass this question id with answer to view? Now I'm getting only the answer (choice)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the question id as hidden value as shown below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="{{ question.id }}">
{% for radio in answer_form.choice %}
    <label><input name="choice" type="radio" value="{{ radio.choice_value }}" onchange="question_{{ question.id }}.submit()">{{ radio.choice_label }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm not getting this hidden input in response:
`<tr><th></th><td><ul id="id_choice"><li><label for="id_choice_0"><input id="id_choice_0" name="choice" type="radio" value="0" required /> Точно ні</label></li>
...
<li><label for="id_choice_4"><input id="id_choice_4" name="choice" type="radio" value="4" required /> Точно так</label></li></ul><input id="id_question_id" name="question_id" type="hidden" /></td></tr>`

Comment: You should get it,  if you are able to receive radio button value.

Comment: As you can see I'm getting `<input id="id_question_id" name="question_id" type="hidden" />` from form `question_id = CharField(widget=HiddenInput(), required=False)`. But also I tried to rewrite form with Form, not ModelForm.
And I'm not getting hidden input at all....